# Populate a multivalue image field when importing xml data with Feeds

Tags: feeds

I created an importer to fetch data from an http xml file. To create the importer I'm using [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) and [Feeds XPath Parser](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_xpathparser)

So far so good. Thing is that the xml file has several images to import in a single multivalue image field of my nodes.

Then I guess I have to concatenate these images into one value and then after populate my field. To do this I'm using [Feeds Tamper](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper). This one allowed me to REWRITE the multivalue image field using tokens where I set one token for each image. 
It seems simple but it doesn't work. What am I missing here?

Is there any other way to do this?

Image capture of the xml: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B71-gfIvQWAUU3ZpWVpVZzJjTFk/view

Comment: How did you give the path to the images? In a similar scenario I had to use public://path/.. which means sites/default/files/path/.. and I concatenated the images by using semicolon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For Multi-Valued field you could use `Explode` Plugin in feeds Tamper
- Also Use `Trim` Plugin to Remove white spaces if any in Image URL.
- Reference: [Feeds Example](https://www.drupal.org/node/2287473)

[image]

Comment: I need to do just the oposite. The xml has the images separated. I need to concatenate the images into one field. Look my capture: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B71-gfIvQWAUU3ZpWVpVZzJjTFk/view?usp=sharing